# Rotate a block in beamer

Tags: beamer, rotating, block

I wanted to add an example in my beamer presentation and I wanted the complete example block to be rotated by 90 degree. How I can do it? I have tried using following code but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{example}
   Hello world
\end{example}
\end{turn}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the example block in `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
  \usetheme{Singapore}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{turn}{90}
      \begin{minipage}{5cm}
        \begin{example}
          Hello world
       \end{example}
     \end{minipage}
   \end{turn}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```